# User ask how many input you want to take and then show their sum in mips

Tags: loops, mips

I want to make a program in mips, in which the user will enter the number of inputs he wants to take. Finally the program will print the sum of the inputs.

Here is my code:

```
 .data

    myMessage:  .asciiz "ENTER numbers you want to sum\n"
    value:      .asciiz "ENTER  Value \n"

    sum :       .word 0


 .text

    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, myMessage
    syscall

    li $v0, 5
    syscall

    move $t0, $v0         #num of time user will enter num

    la $t1, 0         #count value first initiallize to 0

see:
    bne $t1,$t0,add         #checking if  count is less than the num of value 



    li  $v0, 1              #printing sum finally
    la $a0, ($s2)

add:
    li $v0,4
    la $a0,value
    syscall

    li $v0,5
    syscall

    move $t3,$v0


    la $a1, sum     #load address of 'bal' in '$a1'
    lw $s3, 0($a1)      #load sum from '$a1' to '$s2' (initially 0)
    add $s3, $s3, $t3   #adding the sum 
    sw $s2, 0($a1)      #load latest sum ('$s2') in .word balance ('$a1')

    addi $t1,$t1,1                    inc in count

    j see
```

The problem is that the program does not stop after the wished number of inputs and continues to ask for new input.

Answer (score 0):

```
.data      # Data declaration section

    instring1:    .asciiz  "ENTER numbers you want to sum\n"
    instring2:    .asciiz  "Enter value\n"
    outstring:    .asciiz  "Sum: "

.text#
main: 
#Print instring1
    li $v0, 4           # system call code for printing string = 4
    la $a0, instring1   # load address of string to be printed into $a0
    syscall             # call operating system to perform operation in $v0
                        #     syscall takes its arguments from $a0, $a1,

#Taking n as input
    li $v0, 5 # read int
    syscall
    move $s0, $v0 # the result of the syscall is stored in v0
                # we move it to t0 to prevent overwriting

#Creation heap memory
    mul $t1, $s0, 4
    li $v0, 9
    move $a0, $t1
    syscall
    move $s1, $v0
        

#Print instring2
    li $v0, 4           # system call code for printing string = 4
    la $a0, instring2  # load address of string to be printed into $a0
    syscall             # call operating system to perform operation in $v0
                        #     syscall takes its arguments from $a0, $a1,

    li   $s2, 0         # $s2 is the index, and loop induction variable
        
Start_Input:  
    bge  $s2, $s0, End_Input

    li $v0, 5           # Read integer values
    syscall
    
    mul  $t0, $s2, 4    # $t0 is the offset
    add  $t1, $s1, $t0  # $t1 is the address of desired index
    sw   $v0, ($t1)     # store the value in the array
    addi $s2, $s2, 1    # increment the index        
    j    Start_Input

End_Input:
    add $t0, $zero, $zero # i is initialized to 0, $t0 = 0
    add $s2, $zero, $zero # sum = 0
    beq $s0, $zero, print_sum # if number = 0 then goto print_sum

Loop: #stuff
    mul $t1, $t0, 4
    add  $t2, $s1, $t1
    lw $t3, ($t2)
    add $s2, $s2, $t3

    addi $t0, $t0, 1 # i ++
    slt $t1, $t0, $s0 # $t1 = 1 if i < n
    bne $t1, $zero, Loop # go to Loop if i < n

#Print Sum
print_sum:
    li $v0, 4           # system call code for printing string = 4
    la $a0, outstring   # load address of string to be printed into $a0
    syscall             # call operating system to perform operation in $v0
                        #     syscall takes its arguments from $a0, $a1,
    li $v0 1 # print int
    move $a0 $s2
    syscall

#Exit Syscall
EXIT:
    li $v0 10# exit
    syscall
```

This is working code. Comment provided to understand code.

Answer (score -1):

```
.data 
myMessage:.asciiz "ENTER numbers you want to sum\n" 
value:.asciiz "ENTER  Value: "
show: .asciiz "\nSum is: "
.text 
li $v0,4 
la $a0,myMessage 
syscall 
li $v0,5 
syscall
move $t0,$v0    #num of time user will enter num
la $t1, 0   #count value first initiallize to 0
la $t5, 0
see:
bne $t1,$t0,add #checking if  count is less than the num of value
li $v0, 4
la $a0, show
syscall     #print message "Sum is: "
li $v0, 1
move $a0, $t5
syscall     #print the result
j end
add: 
li $v0,4 
la $a0,value 
syscall
li $v0, 5
syscall
add $t5, $t5, $v0
sub $t0, $t0, 1
j see
end:
```